# How to make home directory of existing users?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

while read firstname lastname userid 
do 
     sudo useradd -c "${firstname}.${lastname}" -d /home/students/student/"${firstname}.${lastname}" -G students -s /bin/bash "${userid}"
done < hello.csv
```

Comment: You might want to investigate the `newusers` command (*"update and create new users in batch"*)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/useradd.8.html):

> ```
> -m, --create-home
>     Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. 
>     The files and directories contained in the skeleton directory
>     (which can be defined with the -k option) will be copied to 
>     the home directory.
>
>     By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME 
>     is not enabled, no home directories are created.
> ```

However, I would *strongly* suggest to *not* use a user's real name
for the $HOME directory as you did with `-d /home/students/student/"${firstname}.${lastname}"`. 
Think of (real) usernames like "John A. Doe".
His $HOME directory would contain a space and that is not exactly userfriendly.

Comment: Or someone with a non-latin name. Would not work. Usernames has to match `[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]?` according to `man useradd`

Comment: @vidarlo Not quite. What you say is true for the username (the string you get from `id` or what you need to type when logging in, e.g. `pduck`). But the OP uses the _real name_ for the $HOME path, e.g. `/home/students/student/Perl.Duck`. Here, anything that is a valid filename is allowed but when it contains weird characters you _always_ have to write `"$HOME"` instead of just `$HOME` and I'm tempted to predict that users will keep asking the OP why `cd /home/students/student/John A. Doe` won't take them to their home directory but complain about _cd: too many arguments_ instead.

Comment: Good distinction. I didn't spot that :)

Answer (score 0):

`useradd` creates new users, so if the user already exists (as the question title implies) then it will refuse to create the home directory.

Instead, one can call the helper command

```
sudo mkhomedir_helper "${userid}"
```

which will create the home directory as specified in `/etc/passwd`.